# 'int' object is not callable while calling a function

Tags: python, int, callable, dice

I am an amateur programmer who is working on a console dice roller, quite more complex than the traditional ones. So far I am having trouble with this function:

```py
  def multiRoll(dice, amount):
        total = 0
        rolls = []
    for roll in range(amount):
        rolls += roll(dice)
    total = sum(rolls)
    return total, rolls
```

It *is meant* to take a single entry from a dictionary describing the kind of dice (4, 6, 8 faces, etc.) with its index and the times the dice is rolled. Then it rolls the dice as much as it is needed and then it is meant to add each result into a single list that will be summed later.

But apparently the flux goes wrong and when it reaches the this line:

```
        rolls += roll(dice)
```

I get **'int' object is not callable**.

May you please tell me how to overcome this?

If you have any doubt about the roll() function, here they are:

```py
def roll(dice):
    if dice < 1:
            print "I found a problem when trying to roll a d%d" % (dice)
            return "Failed"
    else:
            return randrange(1, dice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for roll in range(amount):
        rolls += roll(dice)
```

The `roll(dice)` isn't using your function, but rather the `roll` variable of your `for` loop. You should change the variable of the loop to be:

```
for number in range(amount):
    rolls += roll(dice)
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much; you guys were incredibly quick :D

Comment: Ok, I am guessing how this site works, hehe. Thank you guys again. This was fast.

Answer (score 0):

You have reassigned `roll` in

```
for roll in range(amount):
        rolls += roll(dice)
```

Replace it with another variable name:

```
for r in range(amount):
        rolls += roll(dice)
```

Comment: On a side note, the underscore(`_`) is usually used for such "junk" variables. Or you can name it with something more explicit like "junk", "not_used", or in this case "time"(recalling "for x time(s)").
[Note: if you use `gettext` using `_` may not be a good idea]

Comment: Thank you very much; you guys were incredibly quick :D

Comment: @Bakuriu Yup, but the underscore [tends to confuse programmers new to Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python), so I left it out

Answer (score 0):

In this line here:

```
for roll in range(amount):
    rolls += roll(dice)
```

You are creating a local variable called `roll` which is overwriting the function `roll` which you have defined in your program.
What you need to do is change either the function name or the local variable name so that they are not the same.

Comment: Thank you very much; you guys were incredibly quick :D