# int object not callable error in python

Tags: python, object, int, typeerror

This following section of code gave me the error

```
fd=((1/(sd*sqrt(6.28)))*2.718**((-1(d-average)**2))/(2*sd**2)))
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\etc
    fd=((1/(sd*sqrt(6.28)))*2.718**((-1(d-average)**2))/(2*sd**2))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

i cannot find where the int object is "not callable"

thanks

Comment: That's because the expression is hideous. Use a bunch of temporary variables. (My guess is you're missing an operator at `-1(d-average)` before the paren.)

Comment: Your example code and the error message don't have the same code.

Comment: i had that in mind but my professor wants to see the exact equation within the code as he gave it to us. Thanks anyways

Comment: yes but the same error pops up ill fix it

Comment: possible duplicate of ['int' object is not callable while calling a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406859/int-object-is-not-callable-while-calling-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `*` operator after -1.

Comment: For future reference, the error message is quite helpful.  The `'int' object is not callable` tells you that you are trying to do something like <int>(<something>).  I just looked for a place where an int butted up against parens.

Answer (score 1):

This results from an int object that Python is trying to 'call' like so:

```
>>> 2*(1+3)
8
>>> 2(1+3)        #note missing *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```